# Allocation failed - process out of memory

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I am going to compile web-pack i have got issue in that i.e Allocation failed - process out of memory .I know i can increase the space size using this

> --max_old_space_size=8192

i tried many ways to fix this but nothing is working.
here is my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "karma": "karma",
    "test": "karma start",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "webpack": "webpack --progress --profile --bail",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "clean": "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist compiled dll",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:dll": "npm run rimraf -- dll",
    "clean:electron": "npm run rimraf -- build",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "preclean:start": "npm run clean",
    "clean:start": "npm start",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
    "watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
    "watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
    "build:dev": " npm run clean:dist && npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.dev.js",
    "prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
    "build:prod": "npm run clean:dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist -c-1 --cors",
    "server:test": "http-server dist-demo -c-1 --cors",
    "server:prod:ci": "http-server dist -p 3000 -c-1 --cors",
    "webdriver:update": "npm run webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
    "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --force",
    "ngc": "./node_modules/.bin/ngc-w -p tsconfig.webpack.json",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update -- --standalone",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
    "gh-pages": "wintersmith build -C docs && gh-pages -d docs/build",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "build:electron": "npm run build:electron.full",
    "prebuild:electron.full": "npm run clean:electron",
    "build:electron.full": "npm run build:electron.renderer && npm run build:electron.main",
    "postbuild:electron.full": "npm run electron:start",
    "build:electron.renderer": "npm run webpack -- --config config/electron/webpack.renderer.prod.js",
    "build:electron.main": "npm run webpack -- --config config/electron/webpack.electron.prod.js",
    "electron:start": "electron build",
    "build:aot:prod": "npm run clean:dist && npm run clean:aot && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build:aot": "npm run build:aot:prod",
    "clean:aot": "npm run rimraf -- compiled",
    "build:ci": "npm run build:prod && npm run build:aot"
  },
```

and the command for running my package.json is

> npm server

please help my out how i increase size.

Comment: How much RAM is on the computer?

Comment: it works perfectly fine on my system , currently i am try to run it on server and on server RAM is 2gb

Comment: 2gb is propaply not enough RAM for webpack to bundle your application, our enterprise app needs for example at least 5gb during compile time.

Comment: can i increase memory using this --max_old_space_size=8192

Comment: Yeah but you can't increase you server's hardware memory with that.

Comment: I need 4GB to build the Angular CLI example app on a Linux machine.

Comment: thanks, @cgTag .by the way I can fix this using 2gb RAM and 16gb ROM

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I was using node version 8.x. Downgrading it to 6.11.0 resolved my issue.